Traveling limitations with J1 Visa
I am considering doing post-doctoral research in the US at a Federal institute. It is my understanding that I'll need a J1 Visa. Since my partner would not relocate to the US, I am trying to understand whether it would be possible for me to work remotely from time to time. Based on online information, I understand that traveling for more than 30 days requires an authorization. What I do not understand is whether there is a limitation on how many times I can travel abroad (e.g., traveling 3 times a year, each time for less than 30 days).

Get clarity beforehand on what the requirements are to allow you work remotely (and from abroad). As an example, I cannot take my work laptop out of the country, I need to get a loaner from security folks. It has very limited connectivity allowed.

Good point. I believe they have very strict requirements but a former employee told me they were working remotely from their home country from time to time. Let's see.

This is probably a better fit for [Expatriates.SE].

The authorization for the >30 days absence needs to come from the employer, same as the authorization for remote work. You'll need to discuss that with them.
